# I keep getting stuck in an infinite loop with my password checker

Tags: java, infinite-loop, password-checker

Every time I run this program I keep coming up upon an infinite loop that keeps repeating the else statement "this password is incorrect" every time I run this program

also what other mistakes did I make here if there is any?

```
public static void ValidChecker() {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        boolean correct = false;
        while(correct == false)
        System.out.println("please enter a password");
        String pass = scanner.next();
        for(int i = 0; i<pass.length(); i++) {
            if(pass.charAt(i) == '!' && pass.length() > 8 ) {
                System.out.println("this password is correct");
                correct = true;
                    break;
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("this password is incorrect");
                break;
            }
            
        }
```

Comment: "*`while(correct == false) System.out.println("please enter a password");`*" - There is your infinite loop. I suspect that there is an `{` (and a corresponding `}`) missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a MRE of your code that fixed that you can run and try yourself.
Please make sure you understand where you went wrong so you wont make this mistake again :)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        boolean correct = false;
        while(correct == false) {
            System.out.println("please enter a password");
            String pass = scanner.next();
            for(int i = 0; i<pass.length(); i++) {
                if(pass.charAt(i) == '!' && pass.length() > 8 ) {
                    System.out.println("this password is correct");
                    correct = true;
                    break;
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("this password is incorrect");
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The mistake in your code was the missing curly braces (The `{` at the start and `}` at the end of your loop). Remember, conditions like `if`, `while` etc. will only run the first line after the condition if there are no curly braces. Which in your case it would run `while(correct == false) System.out.println("please enter a password");`, where `correct` never becomes false. So it ends up looping infinitely printing "please enter a password".

Comment: thank you a ton, because of this fix I managed to fix everything else wrong with the program

Comment: Just hope you don't make the mistake again :>